Centering columns AND aligning them by decimal in gt table
I want to align columns in gt table by the decimal mark but I also want them to be centered. Is that possible? It seems that you cannot do both at the same time?
install.packages("librarian")
librarian::shelf(tidyverse, gt)

data <- 
  tibble(group = c(1:5),
       type_1 = c(1200, 3000, 100, 3300, 5200),
       long_label_type_2 = c(2000, 120, 1200, 350, 2300))

Center-align all columns.
data %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  cols_align(
    columns = everything(), 
    align = "center") %>% 
  fmt_number(
    columns = everything(),
    decimals = 0)


Align the type columns by decimal mark.
data %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  cols_align(
    columns = c(group), 
    align = "center") %>% 
  cols_align_decimal(columns = c(type_1, long_label_type_2)) %>%
  fmt_number(
    columns = everything(),
    decimals = 0)



Here's a workaround with formatC and courier new (or any monospaced font):
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

# Toy data
my_data <- tibble(
  group = c(1:5),
  type_1 = c(1200, 3000, 100, 3300, 5200),
  long_label_type_2 = c(2000, 120, 1200, 350, 2300))

# Formatting with `formatC`
# └ All numbers as strings with the same length
my_data<- my_data %>% 
  mutate(across(
    contains("type_"),
    \(x) x %>% 
      formatC(digits = 0, big.mark = ",", format = "f") %>% 
      str_pad(width = max(str_length(.)), pad = " ")))      

# The table
# └ The monospaced font ensures the alignment
my_gt_table <- my_data %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  cols_align(columns = everything(), align = "center") %>%
  tab_style(                                                     
    style = cell_text(font = "courier new", whitespace = "pre"), 
    locations = cells_body(columns = c(type_1, long_label_type_2) ))

# Output
my_gt_table


Created on 2024-05-07 with reprex v2.1.0
Hope it helps.
